# Book from childhood about a teenager whose uncle was a wizard and people were chasing them trying to kill them

Tags: story-identification, books

I remember a book with an outrageous title like "Lamborghinis, Helicopters, and Wizards". There was a teenager whose uncle was a wizard and people were chasing them trying to kill them.

Comment: When was your childhood? Do you remember anything about the cover? Paperback? Hardback? EBook? Was it in English? Did the teenager have powers?

Comment: I guess the title is a riff on [Planes, Trains and Automobiles](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planes,_Trains_and_Automobiles). The problem is that there don't appear to be any fantasy books with titles containing even two out of the three words you remember so there isn't any way to search the usual book databases. Unless you can remember some distinctive elements of the plot this is going to be hard.

Comment: @JohnRennie - ISFDB contains no books with the titles... "... and wizards", "... and mages", "... and sorcerors".

Comment: Nor apparently does Goodreads. Neither of them is infallible of course, but to have drawn a blank on both is discouraging.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/20774) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add. For example, what was the teenager's name? Was it just this teen and his/her uncle? Was the teen male or female? Who were they running from? Did they literally get to use all the modes of transport mentioned in the title? What was the setting (modern/futuristic)? What was the hero's name? What did he look like? Was he a young teen or older teen? What did the book cover look like?

Answer (score 5):

Hmm, not much to go with. Let's try this one. What you think is a title might have been a blurb on the book cover.
Might be "The Pendragon Adventure" series of books.

https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Literature/ThePendragonAdventure

The hero is 14 year old Bobby Pendragon, cool uncle is Uncle Press, who comes for Bobby in the first book with motorcycle and is a Traveller, a wizard-like human who can move between worlds. I forgot in which book he takes Bobby on a helicopter ride, but Uncle Press likes to travel in style. So, fancy cars, motorcycles, helicopters, chariots...

Books in the series are
The Merchant of Death (2002)

The Lost City of Faar (2003)

The Never War (2003)

The Reality Bug (2003)

Black Water (2004)

The Rivers of Zadaa (2005)

The Quillan Games (2005)

The Pilgrims of Rayne (2007)

Raven Rise (2008)

The Soldiers of Halla (2009)

So, if you read them around that time, it might be it.

Comment: The blurbs don't seem to match the description given; https://m.media-amazon.com/images/I/91gxulE9YTL._AC_UF894,1000_QL80_.jpg + https://m.media-amazon.com/images/W/MEDIAX_792452-T2/images/I/91vqIG7iteL._AC_UF350,350_QL80_.jpg